# aparecer uma div consoante a select escolhida

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma select, e consoante a escolha dessa mesmo select, vai ser mostrado um formulário para inserir um contacto. Tenho que ter em atenção que a primeira opção da select já tem o formulário a ser mostrado por defeito, ou seja, o utilizador quando abre a página aparece logo o formulário empresa. Tenho o seguinte:

```
<select name="id_tipo_contacto" id="id_tipo_contacto">
    <option value="1">Contacto empresa</option>
    <option value="2">Contacto casamento</option>
</select>

<div id="empresa" style="display:none;">
      Mostra formulário empresa
</div>

<div id="casamento" style="display:none;">
      Mostra formulário casamento
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A melhor solução é dar uma classe a essas divs que têm formulários para as poder selecionar. Depois, dê o nome da `ID` de cada div ao `value` da `option` no `select`.

Exemplo:

```
<select name="id_tipo_contacto" id="id_tipo_contacto">
    <option value="empresa">Contacto empresa</option>
    <option value="casamento">Contacto casamento</option>
</select>
<div id="empresa" class="formulario">Mostra formulário empresa</div>
<div id="casamento" class="formulario" style="display:none;">Mostra formulário casamento</div>
```

Assim só precisa de fazer assim, usando JS puro: http://jsfiddle.net/c4hyM/

```
var select = document.getElementById("id_tipo_contacto");
var formularios = document.querySelectorAll('.formulario');

select.onchange = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < formularios.length; i++) formularios[i].style.display = 'none';
    var divID = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    div.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Se quiser usar jQuery, pode usar assim: http://jsfiddle.net/c4hyM/1/

```
$("#id_tipo_contacto").on('change', function(){
    $('.formulario').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio!

Answer (score 2):

Se tiveres apenas duas opções ate podes fazer de forma estática em javascript:

```
alteraDiv = function (){
if($('#id_tipo_contacto').val() == 1){
    $("#empresa").show();
    $("#casamento").hide();
}

if($('#id_tipo_contacto').val() == 2){
    $("#empresa").hide();
    $("#casamento").show();
}
```

Deixo aqui [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/aR7uF/)

Dinamicamente a resposta do @Sergio está bem completa