# Alterar CSS de elemento dependendo da opção no SELECT usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em realizar uma determinada interatividade no meu site.
Por exemplo, há um `select` no HTML com 3 `options`, e quando o usuário selecionar determinado `option`, haveria uma alteração no CSS de um elemento, tudo isso usando jQuery.

Como eu poderia setar o valor desse option e em seguida fazer a verificação que preciso?

Trecho descrito:

```
<select name="tipoCliente" id="tipo_cliente">
    <option>Selecione*</option>
    <option value="Tipo 1">Tipo 1</option>
    <option value="Tipo 2">Tipo 2</option>
    <option value="Tipo 3">Tipo 3</option>
</select>
```

CSS do elemento a ser alterado dependendo da opção selecionada acima (por padrão ele é `none`, depois da seleção ficara `block`):

```
#formsgeral{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Pode mostrar os fragmentos relevantes do seu código?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25440/aparecer-uma-div-consoante-a-select-escolhida/25442#25442

Comment: @Sergio, eu quase voto como duplicata... a solução lá é a mesma que cá, não? O que acha, Kaleb?

Comment: Tem razão @brasofilo. Estou executando da mesma forma do relacionado. Valeu cara! E obrigado @Sergio! :D